# iOS Build getting disappears from iTunes connect after few seconds of processing Xcode 11.6

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiwebview, app-store-connect

The build was successfully validated and showing in "Activity" tab of iTunes connect showing as "Processing". once you refresh the iTunes connect portal, it got disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Thre are many reasons for this issue.
I faced it when I used **UIWebview** framework which is deprecated.
We should use "WKWebView".

[Apple News about UIWebview](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12232019b)

Answer (score 0):

Usually You need to check your mail for knowing the reason.
The most common reasons: UIWebview or lack of privacy keys descriptions in info.plist (like NSCameraUsageDescription, ect.)